# WSO2 APIM: Configuration variables

Tags: wso2, configuration-files, wso2-api-manager

(I know that this sounds as a newbie questions, but, you know, really, I don't finde the answer in docs)

In WSO2 products, and specifically in API Manager (2.1.0), we have to modify a lot of configuration files just to start.

We have seen that some configuration files (api-manager.xml, carbon.xml) use configurations variables. E.g., ${admin.username} to substitute by admin user.

We have found an old post (2016) explaining the use of configuration variables in WSO2 products

https://medium.com/@shan1024/overriding-configurations-in-wso2-products-using-deployment-properties-file-f096e96f782d

But we are not able to find the `deployment.properties` files referenced in that post, neither and official documentation.

Do you know if this works in APIM? Where have I to install this file?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, deployment.yaml was introduced in Carbon kernel 5.2 onwards. But WSO2 APIM 2.x is based on Carbon kernel 4.4.X. Therefore APIM 2.x doesn't support that. 
WSO2 APIM 3.X will support this feature.

Comment: Thanks! And do you know how/where the variables are set currently (${admin.username}) and so on...

Comment: @Sourcerer just keep the `${admin.username}` as it is, it is replaced "by itself", however for other things (hostnames, userstore, .. ) you need to write templates yourself. Another interesting option would be using puppet deployment (wso2 already provides some "puppetized" projects, just search for for it)

Comment: Thanks, @gusto2. In the documentation I saw that puppet modules are discontinued. We are using some puppet scripts in AWS (Cloudformation), but still have problems to replace parms. Finally we are using bash scripts with xmlstarlet to configure (complex and error prone)